# Create an Excel Pivot Table with columns that are a percent off the row total, but the row total displays as counts?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

Background:
I am creating many **pivot tables** in Excel 2010 with a fixed number of rows, and a differing amount of columns.  I'm currently creating them by copying and pasting and swapping out the column field.  It's efficient enough.

My issue:
I'm showing values as the percent off the row total, but the row total itself shows as a percent off itself which is always 100%.  I want the reader to be able to see the row total count, so I've added an extra value field to display that, which makes the table a bit crowded.  So what I'm ultimately trying to do is have the column field values display as percent off the row total and the row total just display as a count.

Is there a simple solution that doesn't involve VBA?

Comment: Can you paste an example of what it shows now and what you want it to show?

Comment: no answer? I have the same request

Comment: It isn't possible.